# Does anyone have an XML namespace for Salesforce's APEX?

Tags: xml, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to use xmllint to reformat our VisualForce code.  My command line is "xmllint --format --recover filename.page".

Though the formatting (especially script sections) work out well, all the tags with apex inside them are modified to eliminate "apex."

For instance, "apex:page" is replaced with "page.".  Obviously, this makes the reformatting useless.

While processing, xmllint complains about the namespace.  In the example below I just use the namespace "ns."  Notice how the output removes the "ns."

```
tgagne@ubuntu:~/tmp$ xmllint --format --recover a.xml
a.xml:1: namespace error : Namespace prefix ns on a is not defined
<ns:a>
     ^
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
</a>
```

Comment: A quick work-around might be to add xmlns attributes to the outer-most apex:page tag for both the apex and c namespaces.

Comment: That's what I would try first.

Comment: your file's root xml element obviuosly lacks a namespace declaration for 'ns'. define it by adding an xml attribute `xmlns:ns="http://whatever_unique_uri_you_wish"` inside the file `a.xml`or configure your toolchain generating the file to add that declaration. regarding the `apex` elements, maybe the default and apex namespaces set on the root element are the same? regards

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer that collapsar made, here are some of the namespaces that are used in Salesforce's Enterprise WSDL.  Might be a good idea to start with these, or take a look at the other WSDLs they have published.  (See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner.htm for more details.)

xmlns:tns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"

xmlns:fns="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"

xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"

Edit:  Just took a look at the metadata for our Apex classes and found this namespace, which might be useful:

xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"